# React Hot Loader v3. this component is not accepted by Hot Loader

Tags: reactjs

I've updated `react-hot-loader` to `v.3.0.0` and when I change something in component I get updates in the browser but I also get this warning in the console:

> React Hot Loader: this component is not accepted by Hot Loader. 
>   Please check is it extracted as a top-level class, a function or a
>   variable.  Click below to reveal the source location:

The problem is I'm not seeing anything in the stack which would suggest me where is the error.

**webpack entry**

```
client: [
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  'wicg-focus-ring',
  PATHS.clientBundleEntry,
],
```

**eslint**

```
"plugins": [
    "react-html-attrs",
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "styled-jsx-postcss/babel",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
```

**client.jsx**

```
function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          {app}
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('app'),
  );
}

render();
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./app', () => { render(); });
}
```

[image: stacktrace]

**EDIT:**

I have changed:

```
export default withRouter(
  connect(
    (state: ReduxState) => ({
      error: state.requestState.loginError,
    }),
    { loginUser },
  )(LoginContent),
);
```

into:

```
const withRouterLoginContent = withRouter(LoginContent);
export default connect(
  (state: ReduxState) => ({
    error: state.requestState.loginError,
  }),
  {
    loginUser,
  },
)(withRouterLoginContent);
```

... and it helped in **some** cases. Not sure what's the difference though.

Comment: Hi, I see you talk about `It had to do with Components composed with HigherOrderComponents like: ... ` What exactly do you change in your client.js? Or it is outside client.js ? Please enlighten me!

Comment: @MervynLee I assume you understand what HigherOrderComponent is (a function that takes the component and returns component). So you see in my examples that I used `withRouter` and `connect` HOCs, but I have inlined them, I didn't split up these assignments. That was causing the error(with a new version of HotLoader it is a warning). When I split up the work (or composition) to steps it helped. It had nothing to do with `client.js` but a way I used to `export` components.

Comment: I see that you have experience in webpack and react. I am currently facing some problem on deployment and several doubts. Can I contact you in term of email or some chatroom to clarify them? Thanks

Comment: @MervynLee fine, I would prefer stackoverflow chat or something.

Comment: I have solve most of them. Maybe I can ask here: I don't think I got any HOC in my source code that coded that way which will trigger the warning. When I deploy them, the warning is gone. Should I ignore the issue?

Comment: @MervynLee It's a just warning now so not a big deal. Anyway, it's just for development so production code won't be affected in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I experienced this same problem and was able to solve it by not using "functional composition" to combine multiple higher-order-components, [as described in React Hot Loader's Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#react-hot-loader-this-component-is-not-accepted-by-hot-loader).

Their "solution" at the bottom of the page fixed the warning for me. Reproduced here, it's a matter of converting:

```js
const SuperComponent = 
     connect()(         <-- last HoC
       withSomeStuff(   <-- first HoC
         Component      <-- a real component
       )
     );
```

To:

```js
const WithSomeStuffComponent = withSomeStuff(Component);
const SuperComponent = connect()(WithSomeStuffComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't `recompose` work in the second way? I'm using `recompose`, but getting lots of these errors.